# Xamarin : reserve items in a list before loading data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

In mobile applications when there is a product list to display, very often to wait for the data to load, the locations appear in gray, which avoids a accordion effect when loading text and images.  I would like to know what is the best way to do this with this Xamarin form?  if you have an example.  thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already use a collectionView, thank you for your answers, here is more using IsBusy to determine if the webservice is being called

```
<CollectionView.EmptyView>
<ContentView x:DataType="viewModels:ProductListViewModel">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
            RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
            <controls:EmptyProductView
                x:Name="EmptyProduct"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
            <controls:EmptyProductView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
        <Label IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBusy}" Text="No data" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
</CollectionView.EmptyView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ListView`, then you can implement an empty list view template and render what you want there while the items are loading. Here is a good example of this feature:

https://github.com/xamcat/mobcat-library/blob/master/MobCAT.Forms/Controls/InfiniteListView.cs#L59-L63

Going forward, I'd recommend switching to `CollectionView` as it's a recommended control for handling lists in a `Xamarin.Forms` app and follow the [guide posted by Jason in his comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview).